# How do I create GitLab CI jobs using the API?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am looking for a way to trigger some GitLab CI jobs, on-demand from another service. Is this possible and if so, how?

Details: imagine that I need to trigger a complex build from an external process.
One workaround that comes into my mind if to have a job-scheduler.git repository that only contains `.gitlabci.yml` file that is rewritten each time I need to trigger a build. I put the code to be run there and that's it. Other ideas?

Comment: So you need to generate a different job each time, or a job list, then trigger the whole dynamic pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the purpose of… triggers: https://gitlab.com/help/ci/triggers/README.md

you then have an api endpoint where you specify the project's id, the trigger token and the git ref.